# Understanding random numbers in iOS Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, random, arc4random

How do I make a random number continue to change over time in the program (I.E. become a new one within the range everytime I want to use it)?

I'm stumped. I've read more than 20 different posts and articles on how to generate random numbers in this language (which I'm pretty new to) and I just can't seem to get it to work.

I'm basically trying to get a random double from 1.0-3.0. I can do this pretty easily, but once it has selected that number it doesn't change. This is my code that I use:

```
var randomNumber:Double = (Double(arc4random() % 3) + 1);
```

Then I use this as a value for the line:

```
SKAction.waitForDuration(randomNumber)
```

Every time I run this I want to change the number again, but once the program starts it continues that same number (It's different every time i reset the program)

I understand how to generate the number, but I can't seem to find anything on updating it!

I've tried adding

```
randomNumber = (Double(arc4random() % 3) + 1);
```

into the code in a spot where it will be ran many times, but it still gives me the same thing.

I'm very familiar with c++ so if you're trying to explain something you can reference its style and I will most likely understand.

Comment: remember `randomNumber` is a variable, not a function pointer, so when you say `SKAction.waitForDuration(randomNumber)` you are really saying var `randomNumber = 3; SKAction.waitForDuration(3)` every time.  You need to 1st create a new random number, then make a new waifForDuration with this new random number,  and add this new action to the sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SKAction.waitForDuration(sec: NSTimeInterval, withRange: NSTimeInterval)
```

where sec is the middle of the range in time you want to use, since range goes in a +- direction.

So in your case you want:

```
SKAction.waitForDuration(2, withRange: 2),  this will get you a range of 1 to 3 (-1 to 1 range)
```

If for some reason you need a method that will constantly create a new random wait, you can always do:

```
extension SKAction
{
    func waitForRandomDuration() -> SKAction
    {
        var randomNumber:Double = (Double(arc4random() % 3) + 1);
        return SKAction.waitForDuration(randomNumber);

    }
}
```

And then make sure that you add this as a new action onto your sprite every time you need to get it done,  if you store it into a variable, your randomness won't change.

Comment: This looks great but how do I impliment it into a SKAction sequence? When I do `SKAction.waitForRandomDuration()` I get the error: "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call." What parameters would I have to input?

Comment: I updated my answer for what you want to be doing,  I almost forgot about the withRange clause.  I do not know why you are getting a missing argument error though when using my method

Comment: Now with this update I get the error `"Extraneous argument label 'sec:' in call"` So I tried omitting that and it worked! Thankyou!!

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to take out the first parameter name,  it is not needed

Comment: This is not an integer wait,  I hope thats ok

Comment: Yea that's fine although other people might like to see that if they're using this as a reference

Comment: you would need to do the extension method, but its a tad more complicated to do it in your scenario,  you pretty much need to make a custom action that will not finish till the requested wait duration

Answer (score 2):

What you need it is a read only computed property that will return a new random every time you try to access it:

```
var randomNumber: Double {
    return Double(arc4random_uniform(3).successor())
}

print(randomNumber)  // 2.0
print(randomNumber)  // 2.0
print(randomNumber)  // 1.0
print(randomNumber)  // 3.0
print(randomNumber)  // 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That makes a lot more sense, the only problem is I think I may have a more specific problem then. I'm using 
`runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(

            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.runBlock(addMonster),
                SKAction.waitForDuration(randomNumber)
                ])`
but when I use your code I still get the same number. Any ideas?

Comment: only problem is my method won't work either,  since the returned action will be static in the way he is using it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
func randomNumberBetween1_0And3_0() -> Double {
    return 1 + Double(arc4random_uniform(2000)) / 1000.0
}

for index in 1...10 {
    print(randomNumberBetween1_0And3_0())
}
```

Sample output is: 
2.087
1.367
1.867
1.32
2.402
1.803
1.325
1.703
2.069
2.335