# How to programmatically add objects to view using Swift 2 (SpriteKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, arc4random

```
import SpriteKit

var counter:Int
var randX = Int(arc4random_uniform(255))
var randY = Int(arc4random_uniform(425))
var coin:SKSpriteNode?



class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //...

    for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
        print("index is \(index)")
        coin = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "gargar")
        coin.frame = CGRectMake(randX, randY, coin.frame.size.width,     
        coin.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(coin)
    }
}
```

Well, I've got the loop. I've got the random numbers for x,y so hopefully, it will remain within CGRectMake bounds? I've looked for questions/answers related to the execution of this but maybe it is so simple that no one has encountered it? Please advise. I would greatly appreciated and pay it forward.

Creatively,
Mensah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - CGPoint Alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114374/swift-cgpoint-alignment)

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: you need to create a computed property besides the fact that your scene might be larger than your view http://stackoverflow.com/a/34891423/2303865

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the position of the sprite, not the frame.

```
coin = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "gargar")
coin.position = CGPoint(x: randX, y: randY)
self.addChild(coin)
```

And if you are trying to create a node from an image, you'll actually use

```
coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gargar")
```

`fileNamed` is for loading `.sks` files, not images.

Keep in mind that the value of randX and randY does not change throughout your loop. You are currently adding 3 sprites at the same position. Move the random point generation inside of your loop if you want them all in different positions.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//created random float using arc4random()
    func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) }
//manipulate that random f. to only return values btwn 0 and 1
    func random2(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return random() * (max - min) + min }
//iterate loop 50x placing enemy position randomly
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 50; counter++) {
//add objects to scene  
    func spawnEnemy() {
            let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gargar")
            enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * random2(min: 0, max: 1), y: frame.size.height * random2(min: 0, max: 1))
            addChild(enemy)
        }
//run SKAction to limit spawnEnemy placement to 1x
    runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemy)]))
```

Comment: Placed within my didMoveToView...this seems to do the trick! Thanks to Leo Dabus and dionlarson for the help. Much appreciated! Cheers!